# how to use upstart?

Tags: django, linux, upstart

I have a django app that i am looking to deploy. I would like to use upstart to run the app.

So far I have added the upstart.conf file to /etc/init

and tried to run it using

```
start upstart
```

but all i get is

```
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.90" (uid=1000 pid=5873 comm="start upstart ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

the contents of the .conf file are:

```
# my upstart django script
# this script will start/stop my django development server
# optional stuff
description "start and stop the django development server"
version "1.0"
author "Calum"


# configuration variables.
# You'll want to change thse as needed
env DJANGO_HOME=/home/django/django-nexus7/nexus7
env DJANGO_PORT=8000
env DJANGO_HOST=0.0.0.0 # bind to all interfaces

# tell upstart we're creating a daemon
# upstart manages PID creation for you.
#expect fork

pre-start script
chdir $DJANGO_HOME
exec /usr/bin/python rm sqlite3.db
exec /usr/bin/python manage.py syncdb
exec /usr/bin/python manage.py loaddata fixtures/data.json
emit django_starting
end script

script
# My startup script, plain old shell scripting here.
chdir $DJANGO_HOME
exec /usr/bin/python manage.py run_gunicorn -c config/gunicorn
#exec /usr/bin/python manage.py runserver $DJANGO_HOST:$DJANGO_PORT &
# create a custom event in case we want to chain later
emit django_running
end script
```

i have also tried using a much simpler .conf file but have come up with more or less the same error. 
Would really appreciate it if someone could give me an idea of what im doing wrong

Comment: What's with the `python rm`, is that valid and correct?

Answer (score 2):

Upstart jobs can only be started by root, and that error appears if you try to start one as a normal user. Try this:

```
sudo start upstart
```